# Can't reference all folders in universal Windows App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

So, I'm writing a universal Windows app and have a referencing problem. When I put all my business logic code in the Shared project, but my views in their respective projects (windows and windows phone), I can't reference the view-folders (I get the c# "the type or namespace could not be found" error). I've checked all namespaces and names, it's all as it should be. And the weird thing is, that *sometimes* I can reference *some* of the subfolders (I have three subfolders in my views folder and right now I can reference two of them and yesterday I could reference only one and before that I couldn't even see the Views namespace). Even when I put the Views folder in the shared project, it isn't all fixed - again I see different folders at different times. So, have I done something wrong, or is the problem somewhere else ?

P.S. I know that paths in windows are case-insensitive, but I've noticed that my windows-phone project (according to VS) is at ~/visual studio 2013/... and the windows project is at ~/Visual Studio 2013/... . In Explorer they are at the same place, but could this mean something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like bad layering, to begin with.  Your (platform-specific) views should hold a reference to your (platform-independent) business logic.  The business logic shouldn't need to be accessing the platform-specific code in the view.

If it really, really has to, you'd need to build a plug-in-like model where there's a platform-independent interface that both platform-specific pieces provide implementations of.

Comment: Well, I've tried to keep to the guidelines of MVVM, so almost all of my navigation happens in the viewmodels. But anyway, the problem is that I can't access the views from _inside_ other views too, not only from inside the viewmodels. If I try to do something like `using App.Views` in the code-behind, it doesn't work (or sometimes it just lets me reference one or two of the sub-namespaces of the Views namespace, but not all of them, which is the weirdest part). I'd share some code, but I'm not sure what would be needed in a case like this...

Comment: Ah, I see -- so the business-logic / view separation is a red herring.  Your views within the same solution can't access each other.  Odd.

Can you browse the classes in the Object Browser?  That may give you some idea of where VS thinks your namespaces lie....

Comment: Hmm, so the Shared project doesn't even exist in the Object Browser and none of the WindowsPhone-specific namespaces are visible either. And some more weirdness - in Shared I only have App.xaml, which, according to the Object Browser, also isn't anywhere to be found, but runs just fine regardless. I tried to create a new Universal Project and the situation is exactly the same, so I guess there's something wrong with VS ?

Comment: Ok, so after reinstalling VS and copying all the contents of the files in a new project (simply opening or copying the existing project didn't work), all seems to be fine. I guess we'll never know what went wrong ...